# How the svm_params in opencv affect my classification?

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I have implemented an image classifer that classifies Vehicles and Animals using SVM.For that i set svm parameters as

```
svm_params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.SVM_LINEAR,
                svm_type = cv2.SVM_C_SVC,
                C=2.67, gamma=5.383 )
```

What is this parameter mean.I understand the kernel_type parameter.But what is svm_type,c and gamma and how this affects my classification.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about svm_type you may find here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html

You should make a nested loop through svm_types and gamma values with generation of confusing matrix, to check quality of your classification and choose the best configuration of svm_type and gamma.

Comment: More gamma value means accurate prediction?

Comment: I don`t think so. I think, that depends on data. 
here is info from docs about gamma:

"Kernel coefficient for ‘rbf’, ‘poly’ and ‘sigmoid’. If gamma is ‘auto’ then 1/n_features will be used instead."

and here you have an explanation, how gamma is computed for 'rbf; kernel function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel